# How to sketch Kush-Kuhn-Tucker problems and its admissible points by hand?

Tags: functions, optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

How do I learn how to sketch the admissible points of functions, such as $$max\space f(x,y)=xy$$ 
with constraints $$4x^{2}+9y^{2}\leq36$$ $$2x+3y\geq6$$

and $$min \space f(x,y)=xy^{2}+5x^{3}y-xy$$
For linear functions, it is pretty straight forward where we set $x$ and $y$ for some numbers set up in a table, and then we can draw from that. But how do we do it for functions where the variables are multiplied with each other?

Thanks

Comment: Hmm that's a little bit non-trivial, so guess your constraints are a plane and an ellipsoid cylinder (maybe there is a name for that?) which are simple enough, but certainly your second surface is not straightforward to my eye(on the first surface you could get **a** plot by direct substitution of the objective into the constraints and plot the 2 constraints). Obviously in terms of actually solving a Lagrangian approach would be efficient for the problems above, conditions looking at bordered Hessian to determine optimality

Comment: In general, is there a generic method to apply? Or do we have to evaluate individual cases as they appear? I know that the best method is that, but often in our exams we are asked to sketch the admissible points to determine if it is bounded or not.

Comment: aah actually if admissible points just means feasible set, then to be honest in the above you just have to sketch a quadratic and a linear function - i.e. you are just looking at the constraints, not the objective fuinction (eg ignore the $xy$ or your second curve. For this simpler problem I think you do just need to know how to sketch certain basic functions that will come up as constraints, doubt these would be more complex than most pre college curve sketching in anything I've seen in these kind of problems

Comment: Oh, ok thanks! I thought I had to sketch my actual function combined with the constraints. But now that it's just the constraints then it's quite alright now. It's actually for a postgrad class in Maths for a Finance. Thanks again!

Comment: no worries do check the definition but like i say cannot imagine they'd get u to sketch the actual intersection of the feasible region with the objective function in general (unless it was a simple example). In this case though note you have 2 variables and 2 constraints including a simple linear one, so potentially substituting all the way through will make a tractable function in one variable drop out, cheers and good luck!